# Upgraded to TFS 2015 - issues due to Database Schema Changed

Tags: database, tfs-2015, reporting-services-2012

We have recently moved from TS 2010 to TFS 2015 Update 2 and using SQL Reporting Services to retrieve various reports for Test Results, Incident/Bug report.

After upgrading to TFS 2015 mostly of the reports we used to run in TFS 2010 (through Reporting Services) do not work anymore as we can notice that Database Schema has been changed massively in TFS 2015 Database.

**For example the following query works perfectly in TFS 2010 Database, however, it does not work at with TFS 2015 database because fields like AreaID, ProjectID, IterationID do not exist in Tbl_Plan anymore.**

```
SELECT      pl.*,<BR>
project.ProjectName,<BR>
area.AreaPath AS AreaPath,<BR>
area.AreaUri AS AreaUri,<BR>
iteration.Iteration AS Iteration<BR>
FROM        tbl_Plan pl <BR>
LEFT JOIN   tbl_Area area ON pl.AreaId = area.AreaId <BR>
LEFT JOIN   tbl_Project project ON pl.ProjectId = project.ProjectId AND project.IsDeleted = 0 <BR>
LEFT JOIN   tbl_Iteration iteration ON pl.IterationId = iteration.IterationId <BR>
```

I would appreciate if someone point me to the right direction to obtain the "Database Diagram" of TFS 2015 database so I can understand the relationships between the tables. This will give us a visual representation to quickly understand their relationships.

Additionally, if you believe that this is not a right way to proceed then advise us as we are open to take any option.

Environment: TFS 2015 Update 2
SQL Reporting Services: 2012

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no Database Diagram of TFS 2015 database available, but there are several types of reporting are available in TFS, you may choose other types instead of SQL Queries to create reports:

- Work Item Queries
- Work Item Reporting
- Out-of-the-box Excel Reports
- Out-of-the-box SSRS Reports
- Team Web Access Charting
- Team Web Access standard reports
- Custom Excel Reports
- Custom SSRS Reports
- SQL Queries
- TFS API
- REST API

Check blog: http://blogs.ripple-rock.com/richarderwin/2014/05/29/TeamFoundationServerReporting.aspx

Answer (score 0):

We noticed that now plan related details are divided into two tables in TFS 2015.
The following query returns the data I was looking for.

```
SELECT tbl_Plan.PlanId AS NewPlanID , tbl_PlanData.* 
FROM tbl_Plan
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_PlanData ON tbl_Plan.PlanId = tbl_PlanData.WitId
```